# How to enable and disable switchCompat accrodingly to database status?

Tags: android

I have an app in which i have a listview with some data stored in sqlite database. Listview also contain switchCompat when i enable switch at index of listview then setting status to "0" and when i disable item then setting to "1". But when status set to "0" it enable swicth and when status set toi "1" it disable switch. Pls help.

code:-

```
  listViewHolder.switchCompat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    boolean isCheck;
    isCheck = !listStorage.get(position).getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("0");

    listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(isCheck);

    listViewHolder.switchCompat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(final CompoundButton buttonView, final boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle).setTitle("Warning").setMessage("You want to whiteList this application?").setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int pos) {
                        //Adding items in Dataset
                        CBlackListModel appList = listStorage.get(position);
                        String appName = appList.getName();
                        String appPackage = appList.getPackName();
                        byte[] appIcon = appList.getImage();
                        String appStatus = "1";

                        appListDataBase.updateApp(appName,appPackage,appIcon,appStatus);

                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(isChecked);

                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(isChecked);
                    }
                }).show();

            } else {
                CBlackListModel model = listStorage.get(position);
                String appName = model.getName();
                String appPackage = model.getPackName();
                byte[] appIcon = model.getImage();
                String appStatus = "1";

                appListDataBase.updateApp(appName,appPackage,appIcon,appStatus);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(false);

                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Removed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

if(isCheck.equals("0")){

listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(true);
}

In adition with it...setchecked false by default in XML.

Comment: Can you check with this  isCheck = listStorage.get(position).getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("0");

Comment: Removing the ! from that line.